# How to set Timezone on whenever gem cronjob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cron, whenever

I am using whenever gem + capistrano to automate my cronjob generation whenever I deploy my app to the live server. Currently the cron that being generated by whenever looks like this(without the timezone "TZ") :

```
30 20 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

My question is, how do I make whenever generate this line together with the timezone (TZ="Europe/London"), so that it will looks like this:

```
30 20 * * * TZ="Europe/London" /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Hope somebody could help..thanks! :)

Comment: Please check this closed issue you may get some idea. https://github.com/javan/whenever/pull/239

Comment: also this might help you https://coderwall.com/p/ahdolq/local-timezone-fix-for-whenever-gem

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default template for jobs like this:

```
set :job_template, "TZ=\"Europe/London\" bash -l -c ':job'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the variable on its own line within your crontab. see man page crontab(5)

```
TZ=Europe/London
30 20 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake overdue_payments --silent >> /home/deploy/apps/myapp/releases/20160123202716/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Comment: OP wants to know how to have whenever generate the timezone configuration, not how to edit crontab to achieve it.